# Node.js generate random unique id and check in mongoDB if exist with Do .. While loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to write, do...while statement. Inside the body generate random id and In a while condition check if exist in DB. If ID not exist, exit from while.
I'm little confused with callbacks and if someone can help me will be very grateful!

It doesn't matter if you have to generate numbers or a string...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

funtion for `do while` loop, I have used `async/await` in place of callbacks.

```
async function checkUniqueId() {

   do {
       id = 'sadfasdrfawerwer';//some generated random id;

   } while (await checkInDb(id));


}
```

function to check id in the db

```
async function checkInDb(id) {
    try {
        let idFound = await User.findOne({ id: id });
        if (idFound) return true;
        else return false;
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return false;
    }

}
```